# regression for prediction of agricultural production

Tags: statistics, artificial-intelligence, spss, prediction

I just got the datas of production, urea, potash, temperature , rainfall, Area used for production. And now i want to design a tool that predicts the production given the parameters.
I used a linear regression model to predict the equation using SPSS. but the equation gives an output that is far different than acutal production.
I did an analysis for the production versus rainfall, production versus temperature. It is a cubical equation.
But for the area its is linear equation.
So should i go for non linear regression to develop the prediction tool or what should i do??
i am confussed.

Answer (score 0):

(1) First of all, you MUST understand that any prediction you make has only the weight of the observed evidence behind it; basically all you can say is "IF EVERYTHING CONTINUES TO WORK AS IT DID BEFORE, which is a big IF, then we expect to get XXX kg/hectare" (or whatever units).

(2) I'm guessing that there is a lot of noise in the data. Make an estimate of the uncertainty of the prediction part of your output. E.g., output the standard deviation of the prediction as well as a point estimate.

(3) I assume that area is a simple multiplier. Divide production by area and predict production per unit area. Multiply by area to get total production.

(4) Low-order polynomials (not more than degree 3) are probably suitable for this problem, but watch out: production must be greater than or equal to zero, but polynomials might not. You can also try some kind of exponential functions, or localized models of some kind (e.g. LOESS, kriging, Gaussian process models).

Good luck and have fun.